# Return 0 if the date for a certain day does not have values

Tags: count

I'm doing a query to return the number of count records for a certain date.
The problem is when I use the GroupBy by a certain day, If the date have no records then the date for that day will not be shown in the output.

How can I achieve that?

I'm doing something like:

```
SELECT COUNT(History.Id)
FROM History
INNER JOIN User ON User.Id = History.UserId
WHERE (@StartDate = @NullDate OR History.CreatedOnDate >= @StartDate)
AND (@EndDate = @NullDate OR History.CreatedOnDate <= @EndDate)
GROUP BY History.CreatedOnDat
```

**Example**

```
01-08, 3 records
02-08, 2 records
04-08, 5 records
```

I need to have 03-08 with 0 records.

Answer (score 1):

Create a temp table with one day per row:

```
Declare @StartDate datetime = '2016-08-01'
Declare @EndDate datetime = '2016-08-31'

declare @temp table
(
oneday datetime
);

WHILE @StartDate <= @EndDate
begin
 INSERT INTO @temp VALUES (@StartDate);
 SET @StartDate = Dateadd(Day,1, @StartDate);
end

select * from @temp
```

Then, simply join your query with this temp table.